# C: Find a pair of elements which sum to a given number X in array

Tags: c

I need help to find an algorithm which can find all the pair of elements in an array whose sum equals to a given number X by O(N) or O(n*log(N)) or O(log(N)).
For example the input is:

```
a[10] = {1, 3, 7, 8, 2, 0, 5, 1, 6, 0} 
x=9
```

And the program should output:

```
1, 8 and 7, 2 both have the sum of 9.
```

I have done my own code with time complexity of O(N^2) which is something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
  {
    /*start from ith element till last element*/
    for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)
    {
      /*if desired length is found, print it*/
      if(a[i] + a[j] == x)
      {
        printf("%d plus %d equals to %d", a[i], a[j], x);
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        printf("Cannot be found");
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: OK. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: This is not how SO works. Your question should be like: "This is my problem, I have tried this to solve it, but I am stuck at this specific point. Can you help me figure out what to do?". First put in the effort yourself, before you ask other people to put in any effort.

Comment: Actually I have my own code but my code is with time complexity of O(N^2). I have used a nested loop and some if statements to get the expected output.

Comment: If you can sort the array first, you can progress from both ends finding the required sum. If the sum of the two elements is too small, increase the lower index. If the sum is too large, decrease the upper index.

Comment: Answer involves arrays ... so `0th` step: **sort the array(s)** ... and if in a later step you realize sorting is not needed, then you can remove step `0` :-)

Comment: @WeatherVane is this method called binary search?

Comment: @pmg Alright thanks!

Comment: No, it is linear (having sorted) but I suppose you could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through this code, I have already solved it a few days ago!

```
/*Algorithm no 1 : */
/*Time Complexity : O(nLog(n))*/
/*Valide for any type of integers*/
bool IsExist_1(int* array, int length, int sum)
{
    int left = 0;
    int right = length - 1;

    while (left < right)
    {
        if((array[left] + array[right]) == sum)
            return true; 
        else if((array[left] + array[right]) < sum)
            ++left;
        else
            --right;
    }
    return false;
}

/*Algorithm no 2 : */
/*Time Complexity : O(nLog(n))*/
/*Valide for any type of integers*/
bool IsExist_2(int* array, int length, int sum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        if(binary_search(array, length, sum - array[i]) != -1)
            return true; 
    return false;
}


/*Algorithm no 3 :
  Time complexity : O(log(n))

 NOTE : This algorithm is only valid for non negative integers and this array must be sorted in ascending order 
*/

/*Time complexity is O(n * n)*/
bool is_exit(int* array, uint32_t size, int sum)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for(int j = (i + 1); j < size; j++)
            if((array[j] + array[i]) == sum)
                return true; 
    return false; 
}

/*Time complexity is O (log(n)) in worst case*/
bool IsExit(int* array, uint32_t size,  int sum)
{
    if(size <= 1)
        return false; 
    int middle_index = size - 1;
    while((middle_index > 0) && (array[middle_index] >= sum))
    {
        printf("middle_index : %d\n" , middle_index); 
        middle_index  /= 2; 
    }
    return is_exit(array, middle_index + 1, sum); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but must we use bool function?

Comment: No, that's not compulsory to use the bool function, you can do anything if there exist some pairs inside the array.